# Get facebook friends list/count with the latest facebook SDK php

Tags: php, facebook-php-sdk

I am having trouble getting a users facebook friends list with the latest facebook SDK PHP 5.0. I have read the documentation from the [Facebook Developers](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.5/user/friends) website but don't really understand it. I have tried the code on the website:

```
/* PHP SDK v5.0.0 */
/* make the API call */

$request = new FacebookRequest(
  $session,
  'GET',
  '/me/friends'
);
$response = $request->execute();
$graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();
/* handle the result */
```

When i try this i just get "Fatal error: Class 'FacebookRequest' not found in /Applications/XAMPP/...". On the [Developer site](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.6/user/friends) at the top of the page it says "This document refers to an outdated version of Graph API. Please use the latest version." But the link does not lead anywhere?? Is this why i am getting a fatal error? I am really not sure what it could be so figured i would ask on here.
This is a copy of my current code:

**Init.php**

```
<?php 
session_start(); 
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php'; 

$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
  'app_id' => '******',
  'app_secret' => '******',
  'default_graph_version' => 'v2.5',
]);

<?php 

require_once 'app/init.php';

$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
$permissions = ['email', 'user_likes', 'user_friends', 'user_birthday', 'user_location', 'user_education_history', 'user_hometown']; // optional
$loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl('http://localhost/Tutorials/FB_login/login-callback.php', $permissions);

if(!isset($_SESSION['fb_access_token'])){
    echo '<a href="' . $loginUrl . '">Log in with Facebook!</a>';
} else {
    echo '<a href="signout.php">Sign Out!</a> <br />';


    $accessToken = $_SESSION['fb_access_token'];
    try {
  // Returns a `Facebook\FacebookResponse` object
      $response = $fb->get('/me?fields=id,name,email,likes,first_name,last_name,birthday,hometown,gender,picture', $accessToken);
    } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
      echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
      exit;
    } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
      echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
      exit;
    }

    $user = $response->getGraphUser();

    echo 'Email: ' . $user->getEmail() . '<br />';
    echo 'First Name: ' . $user->getFirstName() . '<br />';
    echo 'Last Name: ' . $user->getLastName() . '<br />';
    echo 'Name: ' . $user->getName() . '<br />';
    echo 'Birth: ' . $user->getBirthday()->format('Y-m-d') . '<br />';
    echo 'HomeTown: ' . $user->getHometown()['name'] . '<br />';
    echo 'Gender: ' . $user->getGender() . '<br />';
    echo '<img src="' . $user->getPicture()['url'] . '">';
```

All i want to do is echo out a friends list or maybe just a count but have no idea how i can do that. I am really stuck on this and having trouble understanding the documentation. Does anyone know the correct/best way to achieve this?

Many Thanks!

Comment: that looks like a bug in the docs. either way, you can only get friends who authorized your app with user_friends, you know that, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked out the problem just incase anyone else is having the same issue. Firstly you have to go on app review on the FB developer page. Next you have to add taggable friends to your app, use this code and hey presto!!

```
    if (isset($accessToken)) {
    if (isset($_SESSION['facebook_access_token'])) {
        $fb->setDefaultAccessToken($_SESSION['facebook_access_token']);
    } else {
        $_SESSION['facebook_access_token'] = (string) $accessToken;
        // OAuth 2.0 client handler
        $oAuth2Client = $fb->getOAuth2Client();
        // Exchanges a short-lived access token for a long-lived one
        $longLivedAccessToken = $oAuth2Client->getLongLivedAccessToken($_SESSION['facebook_access_token']);
        $_SESSION['facebook_access_token'] = (string) $longLivedAccessToken;
        $fb->setDefaultAccessToken($_SESSION['facebook_access_token']);
    }
    // validating the access token
    try {
        $request = $fb->get('/me');
    } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
        // When Graph returns an error
        if ($e->getCode() == 190) {
            unset($_SESSION['facebook_access_token']);
            $helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
            $loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl('http://localhost/Tutorials/FB/index.php', $permissions);
            echo "<script>window.top.location.href='".$loginUrl."'</script>";
        }
        exit;
    } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
        // When validation fails or other local issues
        echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        exit;
    }
    // get list of friends' names
    try {
        $requestFriends = $fb->get('/me/taggable_friends?fields=name&limit=1000');
        $friends = $requestFriends->getGraphEdge();
    } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
        // When Graph returns an error
        echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        exit;
    } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
        // When validation fails or other local issues
        echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        exit;
    }

    if ($fb->next($friends)) {
        $allFriends = array();
        $friendsArray = $friends->asArray();
        $allFriends = array_merge($friendsArray, $allFriends);
        while ($friends = $fb->next($friends)) {
            $friendsArray = $friends->asArray();
            $allFriends = array_merge($friendsArray, $allFriends);
        }
        foreach ($allFriends as $key) {
            echo $key['name'] . "<br>"; 
        }

        //echo count($allfriends);
    } else {
        $allFriends = $friends->asArray();
        $totalFriends = count($allFriends);
        $counter = 0; 
        foreach ($allFriends as $key) {
            echo $key['name'] . "<br>";
            $counter++;
        }
        echo $counter;
    }

} else {
    $helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
    $loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl('http://localhost/Tutorials/FB/index.php', $permissions);
}
```